# CSS- HTML: dynamically display table rows inline and break new row

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to make 3 table rows display inline so that after 3 rows the table will automatically start on a new line, and continue like this indefinitely?

```
<?php
$addon_name = $_SESSION['Add_On_OpName'];
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX); //overrid a common php nonsense error
$prod_sel = $dbc->query("SELECT *
                           FROM Add_On
                           WHERE Add_On_OpName = '$addon_name'");
$prod_sel->data_seek(0);
while ($output = $prod_sel->fetch_assoc())
{
    $prod_run .= $output['Add_On_OpName'] . $output['Prod_Name'] . $output['Add_On_Price'] . $output['Add_On_Select'] . '<br>';
    $_SESSION['Add_On_OpName'] = $output['Add_On_OpName']; //echo out product name
    $_SESSION['Prod_Name'] = $output['Prod_Name']; //echo out product desc
    $_SESSION['Add_On_Price'] = $output['Add_On_Price']; //echo out price
    $add_on_id = $output['Add_On_ID']; //echo out add on id
    // echo out all add on's and delete button
    echo "

<table style='width:100%'>
  <tr>
    <td id='red_circle'><a id='del' href='delete.php?delete=" . $add_on_id . "'>&times;</a></td> 
    <td><p id='session'>" . $_SESSION["Prod_Name"] . " &nbsp; + " . $_SESSION["Add_On_Price"] . " </p)</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
";
}
?>
```

CSS

```
table {
  width:100%;    
}

tr {
  display:inline-block;
  width:33%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

td {
  display:inline-block;
  width:20%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, with CSS as follows:

```
table {
  width:100%;    
}
tr {
  display:inline-block;
  width:33%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
td {
  display:inline-block;
  width:20%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

This makes the rows 1/3 the width of the table so only 3 fit before they start using the next line. You may also need to set width of the td's so they fit inside the width of the tr, above example works with 5 td's per tr, which renders 15 td's in 3 tr's on one line before breaking.

Comment: Can you post some code? This worked for me in Chrome.

Comment: Your table only has one row. That does not fit the question. Also, you only have two <td> elements, my example was for five, you can't just blindly copy and paste and expect it to work without adapting it to fit your situation.

Comment: Are you trying to format the source code with php? Because that would make it an entirely different question.

Comment: I copied and pasted just to show you it didn't work. I have other css which was very similar to your own

Comment: You first need to fix your closing `</p>` tag you have `</p)`, and where are the other rows you want to display? Where is **your** css?

Comment: The table loops, so every attribute is displayed exactly the same as the first

Answer (score 0):

The width of every table row must be 1/3 of the total width of its parent element, which is the `table` element, since the number of rows that you want for each line is 3. Like this:

JS:
`$('tr').css("width", $('table').width()/3+"px");`

It would be much better if you use `float:left` for the table rows instead of using inline display, because floating elements does not contain spaces. For the table, add `overflow:auto` when floating children elements.